# Ruby regex- matching text if it doesn't start with a character

Tags: ruby, regex

I was wondering how you are able to match a pattern only if it doesn't start with a specific character.  I would like to match "foo" but I would not like to match "afoo."  What kind of regex operator do I need for that?  I can't seem to find the right one.  Maybe an anchor?

For example I'd like to change

```
foo foo afoo foo
```

to

```
bar bar afoo bar
```

Thanks.

Although the answer below is correct for my example, what about if it was /foo instead of afoo?  That doesn't seem to behave the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = "foo foo afoo foo"

str.gsub(/\bfoo/, "bar") #=> "bar bar afoo bar"
```

Comment: What if foo had a / in front of it instead of an a?  Because that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Then follow the suggestion that @mu gave:
`str.gsub(/(?<!\/)foo/, 'bar')`

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're looking for a negative look behind. If you say `(?<!expr1)expr2` then it will match whatever `expr2` matches as long as it isn't immediately preceded by something `expr1` matches. For example:

```
>> 'foo foo afoo foo'.gsub(/(?<!a)foo/, 'bar')
=> "bar bar afoo bar"
```